# ViewSlot with Aurelia throwing an error

Tags: aurelia

Trying to inject **`ViewSlot`** into a skeleton based esnext project, the following error shows up in the browser. I have just created a simple project with the **CLI** based on **`systemjs`** and I see the same thing.

```js
vendor-bundle.js:1398 Unhandled rejection Error: Error invoking ViewSlot. Check the inner error for details.
Inner Error:
Message: Cannot set property ‘viewSlot’ of undefined``
```

From a modified CLI generated app, this reproduces the same problem I see in the real app,

```js
import { BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot, customAttribute, templateController, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(ViewSlot)

export class App {
    constructor(viewSlot) {
        this.message = 'Hello World!';

        this.viewSlot = viewSlot;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it's most likely a problem in your main.js file. Could you provide a link to the skeleton project you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that ViewSlot is supposed to be used with Custom Elements, not with pages. I don't have any problem injecting ViewSlot in to a Custom Element, but it fails every time for me when I try to use it on a page component.

The problem is that a `ViewSlot` instance expects an anchor Node to be passed to it, but a page doesn't have an anchor Node. Aurelia passes `undefined` for the `anchor` property, and then `ViewSlot` tries to set the `viewSlot` property of the undefined value, and that fails.

Comment: Excellent clarification!  stackovf says not to use comments to say thanks, and I cannot upvote yet, so merci :)